# Unexpected result left outer join

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 2 tables with a key for the Column_A, Column_B and Column_C combination. 
I want to left join the rows of Table_A with the rows of table_B. See de query 
beneath. I wanted the result of the first result table, but I get the result 
of the second result table. What do I wrong?

```
Table_A
Column_A    Column_B    Column_C    Other_A
11          1           1           a
11          1           2           b
11          1           3           c
11          1           4           d
11          2           1           e
11          2           2           f
11          2           3           g
11          2           4           h
```

```
Table_B
Column_A    Column_B    Column_C    Other_B
11          1           1           x
```

```
SELECT          *
FROM            Table_A    AS  A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_B    AS  B
  ON            B.Column_A  =  A.Column_A
  AND           B.Column_B  =  A.Column_B
  AND           B.Column_C  =  A.Column_C
```

Wanted Result

```
Column_A    Column_B    Column_C    Other_A Other_B
11          1           1           a       x
11          1           2           b       null
11          1           3           c       null
11          1           4           d       null
11          2           1           e       null
11          2           2           f       null
11          2           3           g       null
11          2           4           h       null
```

Real Result

```
Column_A    Column_B    Column_C    Other_A Other_B
11          1           1           a       x
```

Comment: Where's your "Real Result"? p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the output.  It's consistent with the query.

Comment: If you post the result you want to get, then we can probably help you.  Otherwise, the result looks correct to me.

Comment: @Eric  - yip - looks fine to me too, but there is apparently a real result which is different and which we haven't been shown yet?

Comment: There's no way your query will display your "Real Result" unless you have some `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This is not the real query, In the real query there is a WHERE clause, no TOP clause. The wanted result is what I expect en need, but SQL Server return only one row. I think:
A LEFT OUTER JOIN return al the rows of the left table, and the columns of the right table are assigned when there is a match between the JOIN condition.

Comment: `This is not the real query,`... We're not mind-readers! Please provide **full** information about **a)** your sample data, **b)** your **actual** query and **c)** your desired result and the logic used to obtain it!

Comment: Excuse for the confusion, this is my first question.
a) the sample data is table_A and table_B
b) the actual query is the query in my question
c) my desired result is the "Wanted Result", but SQL Server returns the "Real Result".
Thank you for your response.
Why not all the rows of Table_A are returned?

Comment: Does your actual query have a WHERE or not?

Comment: The result cannot be what you show as "Real" anyway. It would have 8 columns, not 5. How are you running the queries? Through SSMS or something else?

Comment: @user200236 Your `WHERE` condition on the left joined table filter out all of the `NULL` values.  For example: `WHERE OtherB >= x`.  This will filter out all of the values that are `NULL`.

Comment: Please be consistent when you ask.  Post the whole query.  If the query you posted doesn't reflect the current output, how do you expect us to help you?

Answer (score 2):

If that happened it would be a bug.

The probability though that you discovered a bug in a simple `LEFT JOIN` is tiny. Most likely you did something wrong.

> What do I wrong?

We don't know but most probably you are doing *something* wrong. Perhaps:

- this is not the actual query and it has a `WHERE` clause.
- this is not the actual query and there are more joins.
- this is not the actual query and it has a `TOP` clause.
- this is not the actual query and it has a `FETCH FIRST` clause.
- you are missing the statement terminator: `;` and while you think this is the query, there is code after the part you posted (maybe a `WHERE` clause, more joins, etc).
- something else.

So, please check again. Even better, setup a fiddle (eg, in  dbfiddle.uk) and reproduce the issue.